# Operation on elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $Y = xG$ be a point on an elliptic curve, $G$ the generator point and $x$ a scalar. Without knowing $x$, is it possible to calculate $x^nG$, being $n$ a natural number?

Comment: Computing $xnG$ (without exponentiation) would be easy, but I _think_ computing $x^nG$ is not possible w/o knowing $x$ because you only have addition available as operation which only allows you to compute scalar multiplication which would require you to know $x^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is believed to be hard. In fact, even given $G, xG, x^2G,\dots,x^{n-1}G,x^{n+1}G,\dots,x^{2n}G$, you still can't compute $x^nG$; this is called the Generalized Diffie-Hellman Exponent assumption (see Fig. 1 [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/343)).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it can be proven that the problem "given $G, xG$, compute $x^nG$ is equivalent to the CDH problem (for small $n>1$, and assuming that none of the subgroups have a size divisible by $n$).  In particular, given an oracle that can compute $x^nG$, you can, given $xG$ and $yG$ and with $3(n-1)$ queries to the oracle (and a handful of point additions), compute $xyG$.

Here's how it works, for $n=2$, we have:

$$2xyG = (x+y)^2G-x^2G - y^2G$$

Hence, three calls to the Oracle, and a point halving gives the answer.

For $n>2$, we compute $x^2G$ by constructing:

$(x+0)^nG = x^nG$

$(x+1)^nG = \binom{n}{0}x^nG + \binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}G+ … + \binom{n}{n}x^0G$

…

$(x+n-2)^nG = \binom{n}{0}(n-2)^0 {x^nG} + \binom{n}{1}(n-2)^1 x^{n-1}G+ … + \binom{n}{n}(n-2)^n x^0G$

We can treat this as $n-1$ linear equations in $n-1$ unknowns $(x^nG, x^{n-1}G, …, x^2G$, with $x^1G$ being known), and so can solve for $x^2G$.

Then, using the previous technique, we can compute $xyG$ by computing three squares.

We assume that the CDH problem is hard, hence we must assume that the $x^nG$ problem is hard as well...

Comment: Nice, That was I was looking for.